# Eloquent ORM many to many relationship best practices

Tags: php, orm, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables

`cars (id, title)`

`parts (id, title)`

and I want to assosiate every car with a lot of parts and the price of this part for the specific car...

I believe the best way is to associate them through a table:

`car_parts(id, car_id, part_id, price)`

How do I define such a relation in Laravel's Eloquent?

I want to do

```
$car = Car::find(1);
$parts = $car->parts;
```

and I want to get an array of objects like so

```
{
   'id' => 1,
   'title' => 'rear flash',
   'price' => '10.00',
},{
   ...
}
```

if I try the

```
public function parts(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Part', 'car_parts', 'car_id', 'part_id');
}
```

I dont get the price...

TIA

Comment: of course, I wouldn't mind getting an array of objects with `id`, `title`, `car_id`, `part_id`, `price`...

Comment: How does `id` differ from `part_id`? Aren't they both the same thing?

Comment: no, Joseph, they are not. id is the ID of the pivot table holding the car_id and part_id.

Answer (score 1):

The `price` is available on the `pivot` model if you include it in `withPivot`:

```
public function parts ()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Part', 'car_parts', 'car_id', 'part_id')
                ->withPivot('price');
}
```

Then you can `map` over the `parts` collection to get the arrays you want:

```
$parts = Car::find(1)->parts->map(function ($part)
{
    return [
        'id'      => $part->id,
        'title'   => $part->title,
        'car_id'  => $part->pivot->car_id,
        'part_id' => $part->pivot->part_id,
        'price'   => $part->pivot->price,
    ];
});
```

Comment: I did not try that, since I used a completely different approach, but thank you very much!